# favicon.ico:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found) even after adding a link

Tags: html, favicon

I am trying to fix this error:

```
favicon.ico:1          GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

The error came after I added a fetch to a JavaScript function.

I have tried adding `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>` and `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">`, but neither change anything, and for some reason the error only will occur in the console when I press `Ctrl` `F5`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Favicon not working for me using 127.0.0.1 or localhost, but if I use network ip, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Its just simply not there, if the file "favicon.ico" does not exist in the current directory, it will show that error, it just saying that there was an error whilst trying to get the icon, so in your case http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/favicon.ico does not exist, adding a link will not fix that issue.

Comment: then what do I do to fix it? Where should I create a directory called favicon.ico?

Comment: @econo Its not a directory, its a file, and its where the icon is stored (Like the stackoverflow icon in your tabs)

Comment: does it matter where I put the file? What do I put inside it?

Comment: @econo Yes, it has to be in a `.ico` format, you can search up `.png to .ico` online.